# How to compile Bazel on CentOS 6.x?

Tags: centos, bazel

As of today, only Ubuntu packages are available.

Can Bazel be compiled on CentOS 6.x?

Answer (score 8):

Bazel is tested to be able to compile on CentOS 6.7 using the docker image produced by [this docker file](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/test/Dockerfile.centos6.7).
The C++ compiler shipped with CentOS 6.7 is too old to compile Bazel, so the trick is simply to use [a newer one](http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo):

```
# Install the dependencies of Bazel
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel wget which findutils binutils gcc tar gzip zip unzip java java-devel git clang zlib-devel gcc-c++
# Install a newer gcc
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-2.repo
yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-gcc-c++ devtoolset-2-binutils
# Set the path to java and gcc
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0
export CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc
# Clone the repository
git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel /tmp/bazel
# Compile bazel
cd /tmp/bazel; ./compile.sh
# Copy the bazel binary to some binary directory
cp /tmp/bazel/output/bazel ~/bin
```